# Programmatically handle a dynamic range of C# UI form elements

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to optimize my C# code for dynamically showing 1 to 10 elements in a form. The way I currently have it implemented is clumpsy and not very maintenance-friendly, so I did hope it will be possible to rewrite this, to a function that can handle e.g. one element at a time.

I have this below UI form which consists of 10 `textBox` and 10 `pictureBox`:

[image: My form looks like this]

Depending on a `showElements` number I have, then it should show 1 to 10 of these boxes (both the textbox and the imagebox). My current code is this:

```
// How many boxes to show
int showElements = 4;

// Show X elements
for (int i = 1; i <= showElements; i++)
{

    // Show specific element
    switch (i)
    {
        case 1:
            textBox1.Width = width - widthSubstract;
            pictureBox1.Width = width - widthSubstract;
            break;
        case 2:
            textBox2.Width = width - widthSubstract;
            pictureBox2.Width = width - widthSubstract;
            break;
        ... CUT but similar code up to 10

// Hide remaining elements
for (int i = showlements; i <= 10; i++)
switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                textBox1.Visible = false;
                pictureBox1.Visible = false;
                break;
            case 2:
                textBox2.Visible = false;
                pictureBox2.Visible = false;
                break;
            ... CUT but similar code up to 10
```

.. you get the trivial point for the rest. I have more code in each `case` but they all relate to the specific `textBox` or `imageBox` that should be shown.

I cannot figure out how I can optimize this? :-)

Comment: Ever heard of arrays? You don't really need these textBox1... Rather, have an array, initialize it, set properties and add each array item to form's controls.

Comment: `TableLayoutPanel` anyone?

Comment: Suggested solution: Create a Usercontrol with one taxtbox and one pbox. Add or remove instances of this UC to/from a FlowLayoutpanel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add UI elements on demand, instead of pre-defining them within your application.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.Text = "Hello";
    textBox.Tag = i;
    this.Controls.Add(textBox);
}
```

Then re-access them via the Control property.

```
(this.Controls[i] as TextBox).Text += " World!";
```

In your particular case, you could define a custom control, containing a textBox and a PictureBox. Then adding that custom control as a child.

Comment: How would I access the elements - e.g. changing text in a textbox?

Comment: (this.Controls[i] as TextBox).Text = "your new text"

Comment: I found that also myself but it would be nice if you can update your answer for future readers :-) I will accept your answer then as it is easy to relate to.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this :

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication72
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            PictureText[] pictureTexts = new PictureText[] {
                new PictureText { textbox = textBox1, picturebox = pictureBox1},
                new PictureText { textbox = textBox2, picturebox = pictureBox2},
                new PictureText { textbox = textBox3, picturebox = pictureBox3},
                new PictureText { textbox = textBox4, picturebox = pictureBox4},
                new PictureText { textbox = textBox5, picturebox = pictureBox5},
                new PictureText { textbox = textBox6, picturebox = pictureBox6},
                new PictureText { textbox = textBox7, picturebox = pictureBox7},
                new PictureText { textbox = textBox8, picturebox = pictureBox8},
                new PictureText { textbox = textBox9, picturebox = pictureBox9},
                new PictureText { textbox = textBox10, picturebox = pictureBox10}
            };
        }
    }
    public class PictureText
    {
        public TextBox textbox { get; set; }
        public PictureBox picturebox { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: This may be above my expertise in C# ;-) I don't understand how to use the `get` or `set` in this and if it would be possible to have even dynamic number of elements instead of initializing array with a fixed number of elements, this would be best I think.

Comment: The get/set can be ignored it just the syntax the compile likes.  If you want the array dynamic you can use a List<PictureText> instead of the PictureText[]